# Laravel: Update value on button click for approved

Tags: laravel-5.4

Hello I'm still new to laravel and I've searching the web for almost 3 hours about this issue I have I tried many things but it didn't work.

So basicly I have a page with a button, when I click that button "Approved" I want to update the value from 0 to 1 (the column is of type boolean). This is my controller:

```
public function update(Request $request, SubmitApplication $submitApplication)
{
    $submitApplication->update(['approved', 1]);
    return back();
}
```

This is page section with the button it's in the folder trainings and has the name "show.blade.php":

```
<form class="btn-group" action="{{ route('requisitions.update', ['id' => $requisition->id]) }}" method="post">
    {{ method_field('PATCH') }}
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-xs">Approved</button>
</form>
```

I don't see any errors after clicking the button

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you have a modal name  `submitApplication`, if so change your controller to this,

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    submitApplication::where('id',$request->get('id'))->update(['approved'=>true]);
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Comment: What is this error?
Use of undefined constant id - assumed 'id'َ

Comment: soorry my bad `$request->get('id')` , fix this one

Comment: u see i missed ''' in the request body